# Swift Strings and NSString initializers

Tags: string, swift, nsstring

> “…you should almost never need to use the NSString class directly in
>   your own code”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.”
>   iBooks. https://itun.es/us/1u3-0.l

Despite this bold statement, I think I have found a situation where I need an NSString. For instance, consider this code block:

```
NSString(
    contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow"),
    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
    error: &error)
```

I can't do that with a Swift string, right? Either way, this doesn't work:

```
String(
    contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow"),
    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
    error: &error) //Compiler error
```

So should I just use NSString here? Or is there another preferred way to do this in Swift?

Comment: To be fair, you really shouldn't be using `NSString +contentsOfURL:...`, because it makes a synchronous networking request. Use `NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL:completionHandler:` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Foundation framework extends the Swift-native `String` type to have the same initializers as `NSString`, so the documentation *is* correct. (Thanks, *newacct*.)

```
var error: NSError?
let urlString: String? = String(
    contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow")!,
    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
    error: &error)
```

Just make sure to watch your optionals - that initializer for `NSURL` returns an optional that needs to be unwrapped to use in the `NSString` initializer, which itself returns an optional. The compiler may have been complaining about that in typically obtuse fashion.

Comment: If `Foundation` is imported, `String` *does have* initializers for `contentsOf...` and `format:arguments:` in Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that with a `String` the NSURL cannot be nil, but the return from `NSURL(...)` is an optional - you need to unwrap it:

```
var error: NSError? = nil
String(
    contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow")!,
    // NB ! after NSURL(...)
    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
    error: &error)
```

Or more explicitly (and correctly) :

```
var error: NSError? = nil
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://api.stackexchange.com/answers?site=stackoverflow") {
    String(
        contentsOfURL: url,
        encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding,
        error: &error)
}
```

Comment: I tried pasting both of those into a Playground, but both times I got compiler errors.

Comment: This answer is correct for Xcode 6.1, but not Xcode 6.0